# How to change default's colorscheme colours

Tags: colorscheme

I use default colorscheme for Vim since I just love to have consistency throughout my terminal. One thing I don't love though is the colour of number lines, bright yellow doesn't suit it. Is there any way that I can change it and leave the rest of colours as they are? Or is there a way I can make my own colorscheme that uses 16 ANSII colours of my terminal? [image]

Comment: Check `:h hl-LineNr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @klaus mentioned, you want to change the highlight for the group `LineNr`.

In your `.vimrc`, you can change the color of a group with the following:

```
highlight LineNr ctermfg=33
```

`ctermfg` is the variable for a foreground color when using Vim in terminal. There are other options (background, bold, italic...), all described in the highlight help (`:h highlight`).

The number (33 in my example) is the color (from 0 to 255), you can find the list of available colors here for example: https://github.com/guns/xterm-color-table.vim

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have set it to 8 as this is the value for "dark grey" colour of my terminal profile.